# How to use the merge function to merge the common values in two DataFrames?

Tags: merge, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames, I want to merge on the column "Id"

df1 :

```
Id   Reputation
 1     10
 3     5
 4     40
```

df2 :

```
Id   Reputation
 1     10
 2     5
 3     5
 6     55
```

I want the output to be:

dfOutput :

```
Id    Reputation
1       10
2       5
3       5
4       40
6       55
```

I wish to keep all values from both the df s but merge the duplicate values into one. I know I have to use the merge() function but I don't know what arguments to pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [concatenate the DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects), [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) `Id`, and then aggregate by taking the first item in each group.

```
In [62]: pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('Id').first()
Out[62]: 
    Reputation
Id            
1           10
2            5
3            5
4           40
6           55

[5 rows x 1 columns]
```

Or, to preserve `Id` as a column rather than an index, use `as_index=False`:

```
In [68]: pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('Id', as_index=False).first()
Out[68]: 
   Id  Reputation
0   1          10
1   2           5
2   3           5
3   4          40
4   6          55

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

KarlD. suggests an excellent idea; use [combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas-dataframe-combine-first):

```
In [99]: df1.set_index('Id').combine_first(df2.set_index('Id')).reset_index()
Out[99]: 
   Id  Reputation
0   1          10
1   2           5
2   3           5
3   4          40
4   6          55

[5 rows x 2 columns]
```

This solution appears to be faster for large DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 10**6
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':np.arange(N), 'Reputation': np.random.randint(5, size=N)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':np.arange(10, 10+N), 'Reputation':np.random.randint(5, size=N)})
```

---

```
In [95]: %timeit df1.set_index('Id').combine_first(df2.set_index('Id')).reset_index()
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('Id', as_index=False).first()
1 loops, best of 3: 221 ms per loop
```

Comment: This Works, but how do I get the output to be [5 rows X 2 Columns]? I want to retain the Id column. It disappears when I execute this

Comment: Maybe, I misunderstand the question, but can't you just do this with `combine_first` (if you set `Id` as the index). So: `df1.combine_first(df2)`

Comment: @KarlD.: I had thought using `set_index` and `reset_index` would make that rather slow, but in fact, it appears your idea is faster for large DataFrames. Would you like to right it up as a solution?

Comment: Thanks unutbu, I don't think a separate solution is necessary. So if you think combine first is a useful alternative, feel free to add it